# smooth transition with show/hide jquery functions on hover?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, transition

I'm using an image map and when certain part of image is hovered it show div..(like in this website http://jquery-image-map.ssdtutorials.com/) I want the div to appear with smooth transitions...  here is my js code

```
var mapObject = {
    hover : function(area, event) {
        var id = area.attr('name');
        if (event.type == 'mouseover') {
            $('.' + id).show();
            $('#'+ id).siblings().each(function() {
                if ($(this).is(':visible')) {
                    $(this).hide();
                }
            });
            $('#'+ id).show();
        } else {
            $('.' + id).hide();
            $('#'+ id).hide();
            $('#room-0').show();
        }
    }
};
$(function() {

    $('area').live('mouseover mouseout', function(event) {
        mapObject.hover($(this), event);
    });

});
```

Can anyone please suggest me the changes for smooth transitions...
thanks in advance! :)

Comment: `live` is very outdated. what version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: @yuvi jquery-1.6.4.min.js

Comment: give your `show()` and `hide()` a transition duration like `show(500)`

Comment: @AminJafari I want it to be shown for the time user's cursor is on that area! show(500) will make it disappear aftr 500 millsec.

Comment: sorry I misunderstood!

Comment: @AminJafari no prob! :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

So first of all, an unrelated tip - it would be a good idea to update jQuery a bit (if there isn't anything that depends on the old version you are using). `live` won't be available, instead you'll need to replace it with `.on`, but otherwise it's a good idea.

Secondly, sounds like all you're looking for is to give `hide` and `show` some transition. You can simply replace them with `fadeIn()` and `fadeOut()`. You can also use `toggle` which does it all at once (though might misbehave when used with a hover, because it will flip like crazy).

Here's a small snippet that shows you how they work:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  

  var img = $('img');
  
  $('#show').on('click', function() {
     img.fadeIn();
  });
  
  $('#hide').on('click', function() {
     img.fadeOut();
  });
  
  $('#toggle').on('click', function() {
   img.fadeToggle();  
  });
  
  
});
```

```css
* { font-family: sans-serif; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="show"> Show me! </button>

<button id="hide"> Hide me! </button>

<button id="toggle"> Toggle me! </button>

<br>
<br>
<img src="http://www.randomwebsite.com/images/head.jpg" />
```

Of course, those are just shortcut functions that use the `.animate` functionality, which is quite flexible on its own. [Here's a link](http://api.jquery.com/category/effects/) where you can read more about effects and animations in jQuery and how you can use them

Comment: when I changed show() to .fadein() and hide to fadeout(). It didn't respond at all. Can u please modify my code.

Comment: @newbie open the chrome devtools, and look at the console. Do you see any errors there?

Comment: @newbie the link above is still using `show` and `hide`. if you want the change to be animated, either add `.animate` or use one of the shortcuts `fade` functions. What part of that isn't working for you?

Comment: @newbie read about `.animate` and [learn how to use it](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)

Comment: what animate functions can be use to achieve something like this http://tympanus.net/TipsTricks/DirectionAwareHoverEffect/

Comment: @newbie that's a demo from a [tutorial that explains exactly that](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/04/09/direction-aware-hover-effect-with-css3-and-jquery/). It's a bit more complicated, but at its core it uses the same `.animate` functionality (albeit using the more convoluted way of `_applyAnimation`)

Comment: thanx but i have no clue how to integrate it in my code!

Comment: @newbie that's ok. You're new. I can't give you some magic answer that'll make you an expert on the subject, you'll have to learn it. Complicated stuff like that is still a bit much, but pick it up slowly, step by step. You'll get there eventually

Answer (score 3):

Echoing what yuvi said, the 'live' function is deprecated.

I'm not sure why you have your hover function inside an object, but you could also do it like this, using fadeTo:

```js
var mapObject = {
    hover : function(area, event) {
        var id = area.attr('name');
        if (event.type == 'mouseover') {
            $('#'+ id).fadeTo(1000, 1.0);
        } else {
            $('#'+ id).fadeTo(1000, 0);
        }
    }
};

$(function() {
    $('.area').bind('mouseover mouseout', function(event){
         mapObject.hover($(this), event);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="area" name="div1" style="width:20px;height:20px;background-color:#CCC;margin:5px;"></div>
<div class="area" name="div2" style="width:20px;height:20px;background-color:#CCC;margin:5px;"></div>
<div id="div1" style="width:150px;height:100px;background-color:#0F0;display:none;margin:5px;">Image Stand-in One</div>
<div id="div2" style="width:150px;height:100px;background-color:#0F0;display:none;margin:5px;">Image Stand-in Two</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

```js
function smooth(){
   if($("#show").is(":visible")){
    $("#show").hide("1000");
   }
   else{
    $("#show").show("1000");
   }
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href = "#" onclick = "smooth()">Click me</a><br><br>
<h1 id = "show">Shown!</h1>
```